# Script exceeding maximum execution time

Tags: google-apps-script

Can someone help me tidy  this? I'm afraid I am not too technical and have cut n paste various scripts and advice but still timing out....

```
function cleanUp() {
var batchSize = 100 // Process up to 100 threads at once
var delayDays = 10 // Enter # of days before messages are moved to trash
var maxDate = new Date();
maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate()-delayDays);
var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("delete me");
var threads = label.getThreads();
for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
 if (threads[i].getLastMessageDate()<maxDate)
   {
        threads[i].moveToTrash();
      }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first question to answer would be "How many threads do you have with the label delete me" ? 
It appears that you have tried to limit the number of threads to work on at a time by having the batchSize variable but you haven't used it. To work on 100 labels at once, you can modify your loop slightly

```
/* This will work on 100 threads at a time */
for (var i = 0; (i < threads.length) && (i < batchSize) ; i++) {
 if (threads[i].getLastMessageDate()<maxDate)
   {
        threads[i].moveToTrash();
      }
  } 
}
```

On another note, I don't think you can directly deduct the number of days from a `Date` object. You may have to do something like this

```
var ONE_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; //in ms
var delayDays = 10 // Enter # of days before messages are moved to trash
var maxDate = new Date();
var numDays = delayDays * ONE_DAY ; 
maxDate.setTime(maxDate.getTime() - numDays);
```